# Not really sure vs. really not sure

Tags: differences, word-order

Is there any difference between saying "I am not really sure where the noise is from" and "I am really not sure where the noise is from"? are they interchangeable?

Comment: In your example, they are interchangeable - but "I am not really sure" is probably more correct than the idiomatic: "I'm really not sure."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between the two:

> I am not [really sure]

You're anywhere between *almost completely sure* and *quite unsure*. *Really* amplifies *sure*, and *really sure* means you's as good as completely, totally sure. The *not* just says you're not *that* sure yet, or even that you are not *that* sure at all. The exact amount of uncertainty depends on many things like context and intonation. 
I suspect a difference between BrE and AmE as well (cf "quite").

> I am really [not sure]

You're not sure at all! Here, *really* amplifies *not sure*. While *not sure* implies you have doubts, *really* makes that stronger: you have serious doubts.

Another, slightly different example would be:

> I am not completely happy.

Meaning you're happy, but not 100%.

On the other hand, if you change the order (and replace "not happy" with the more natural "unhappy"):

> I am completely unhappy.

Means that you are almost completely unsatisfied; that is almost the opposite of the first version.

Comment: You've got the second one right. But the first 'not really sure' means you're vaguely unsure. Literally you're not absolutely certain, but that leaves a broad range of uncertainty, only slightly or very unsure.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same thoughts about the first -- generally it means that there is a fair amount of uncertainty.

Comment: @Mitch: I added some extra nuance to option 1. I think it depends largely on context. I suspect that especially in BrE "not really sure" _may_ well mean "no way in hell". ("You want me to go skinny dipping in mid winter? I'm not really sure that's such a great idea.")

Comment: @oerkelens there's a lot of pragmatics here, understatement, 'Not really sure' may be a nice way of saying 'No, but I feel bad saying that outright', and 'really not sure' means 'I can't believe you're thinking of bungie jumping what with your hernia, but you're responsible for your own hospital bills'

Comment: This rings true for me. I would say "I'm not really sure" if I'm expressing doubt  and "I'm really not sure" if I'm trying to get someone to stop asking me for my stance on something.